# groovy exclude .svn directory from while traversing thru all sub-directories

Tags: file, groovy, directory

I am trying to traverse through all files and sub-directories excluding `.svn` directory. Can somebody please let me know how to this?

Answer (score 3):

In what regards?  Build tools like GMaven already handle .svn directories.  If you are writing a groovy script to do something on your filesystem, then you'll have to handle it yourself.

Something like:

```
def dir = new File('some/path')
dir.eachFileRecurse { file ->
    if (file.toString().contains(".svn")) { return } 
    // handle your processing
    if (file.isDirectory()) { // do some directory processing
    }
    // etc
}
```

There's a grails page on adding grails to subversion, but I haven't had any problems.

If you're writing build scripts, you may want to consider gradle @ gradle.org  - you get simplified domain specific languages for builds and can mix in groovy to handle special cases